# TaskManager was lost/killed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When I am trying to run the flink job in standalone cluster I get this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: TaskManager was lost/killed: ResourceID{resourceId='2961948b9ac490c11c6e41b0ec197e9f'} @ localhost (dataPort=55795)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.SimpleSlot.releaseSlot(SimpleSlot.java:217)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.SlotSharingGroupAssignment.releaseSharedSlot(SlotSharingGroupAssignment.java:533)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.SharedSlot.releaseSlot(SharedSlot.java:192)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.Instance.markDead(Instance.java:167)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager.unregisterTaskManager(InstanceManager.java:212)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:1143)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:36)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:118)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)`enter code here`
```

Is there any settings which I have to do to avoid this error?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your setup? How do you deploy Flink (YARN, Mesos etc.)? Which version?

Comment: This might help: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/JobManager-shows-TaskManager-was-lost-killed-while-TaskManger-Process-is-still-running-and-the-netwo-td10329.html#a10346

Comment: did you ever found out what was happening?

Comment: Voted to close as additional information was requested years ago but never provided. Without this it is unlikely that this can be solved.